# Correct way to publish elastic search results in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, elasticsearch

I've got a mongodb collection indexed in Elastic Search and want to return the MongoDB documents sorted by their elastic search _score for a given query.

I'm confused as to why the below publication correctly iterates over the documents and updates a (sample) score on each doc:

```
Meteor.publish "docs", (params) ->
  pub = @

  Document.find({}, limit: 20).forEach (doc) ->
    doc._score = 123 # some score
    pub.added 'documents', doc._id, doc

  pub.ready()
```

But the below use of the elastic search client does not return results, and in fact, the iterator is never even executed:

```
Meteor.publish "docs", (params) ->
  pub = @

  client.search
    size: 20
    body:
      query:
        filtered:
          query:
            multi_match:
              fields:['body']
              query: query

  .then (response) =>
    results = response.body?.hits?.hits

    ids = _.inject _.pluck(results, '_id'), (ids, id)->
      ids.push({_id: id}); ids
    , []

    scores = getScores(results)

    Document.find($or: ids).forEach (doc) ->
      # Here is never reached.
      doc._score = scores[doc._id]
      pub.added 'documents', doc._id, doc

  , (error) ->
    console.trace error if error

  pub.ready()
```

I won't be surprised if my approach is way off here. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: your code works!! thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to wait to call `pub.ready()` until after "the initial, complete snapshot of the record set has been sent".  So... at the end of your search success callback.

Docs:
http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_ready

Answer (score -1):

there is a plugin Elasticsearch client for meteor server side. Added methods to easily manage rivering mongo collections and a meteor method to search from the client side.

take a look here : https://github.com/andrewreedy/meteor-elasticsearch

Comment: Deprecated by now